# How to asynchronously call a function with setTimeout twice

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I'm trying to create a typewriter effect with `setTimeout()`.
My code for the typewriter function is as follows:

```
function typeWriter(toWrite,isDelete=false){
    if(!isDelete && i<toWrite.length){
        document.getElementById("typewrite").innerHTML+=toWrite.charAt(i);
        i++;
        speed=Math.random()*100+100;
        setTimeout(typeWriter,speed,toWrite,false);       
    }
    else if(isDelete && i<toWrite.length){
        var typewrite=document.getElementById("typewrite");
        typewrite.innerHTML=typewrite.innerHTML.slice(0,-1);
        i++;
        speed=100;
        setTimeout(typeWriter,speed,toWrite,true);     
    }  
}
```

And I want to call the code twice, once to write a string, and then a second time to delete a part of it.

My grasp on promises is still very shaky, and my attempt (below) didn't really change anything:

```
const intro=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    resolve();
})

intro
    .then(typeWriter("hello world"))
    .then(typeWriter("world",true))
```

When I run the code, instead of having "Hello world" get typed and then delete the "world". Both functions start going synchronously and the final output is "world".

I've been banging my head on this for longer than I'm comfortable admitting, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: you should pass a function to `.then` ... not the result of calling a function - however, since `typeWriter` does nothing with promises, there's no way with the current code to make the second invocation wait for the first

Answer (score 1):

to be chainable, typeWriter has to return a function.

e.g.

```
function typeWriter(toWrite,isDelete=false) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


   })
}
```

If you were to use a setTimout, and you want to wait for the function to be called before going to the next of the chain, place the resolve in the settimeout.

e.g.

```
function typeWriter(toWrite,isDelete=false) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          resolve("hello i am done")
      }, 1000)

   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, I'm using the same syntax as you - e.g

```
.then(typeWriter("hello world"))
```

But in this case, `typeWriter` returns a function, so it's legit

```js
const typeWriter = (toWrite, isDelete) => {
    const typewrite=document.getElementById("typewrite");
    if (!isDelete) {
        const fn = async (position = 0) => {
            if (position < toWrite.length) {
                typewrite.innerHTML += toWrite.charAt(position);
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.random()*100 + 100));
                return fn(position+1);
            }
        };
        return () => fn(0);
    } else {
        const fn = async (position) => {
            if (position < toWrite.length) {
            
                typewrite.innerHTML = typewrite.innerHTML.slice(0,-1);
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
                return fn(position + 1);
            }
        };
        return () => fn(0);
    }
};
Promise.resolve()
.then(typeWriter("hello world"))
.then(typeWriter("world",true))
```

```html
<div id="typewrite"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `typeWriter` immediately, while you really intended to pass that call to the `then` method, and have that only called when the relevant promise resolves. You can do that by passing `() => typeWriter(......)` as anonymous function to `then`.

Secondly, `typeWriter` will then have to return a promise, so the next chained `then` callback will only be called when that promise resolves.

I would also change the signature of your function a bit, so that it first deletes a given number of characters (can be 0) and then inserts the given string.

Here is how that looks:

```js
// Promisify setTimeout:
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// Make async, so it returns a promise:
const typeWriter = async (numDelete, toWrite) => {
    const typewrite = document.getElementById("typewrite");
    // First delete a given number of characters
    while (numDelete-- > 0) {
        typewrite.textContent = typewrite.textContent.slice(0, -1);
        await delay(100);
    }
    // Then append new characters
    for (const letter of toWrite) {
        typewrite.textContent += letter;
        await delay(Math.random()*100 + 100);
    }
};

Promise.resolve()
       // Pass a callback -- don't call typeWriter yourself
       .then(() => typeWriter(0, "hello world"))
       .then(() => typeWriter(5, ""));
```

```html
<div id="typewrite"></div>
```